# jQuery Swap Image on Click and if/else

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im stuck, Im setting a variable when someone clicks, then testing with if to see if the variable exists and doing something else. Its a simple script which Im probably overthinking, would love someone's thoughts.

```
  $('.view-alternatives-btn').live('click', function() {



//$("#nc-alternate-wines").scrollTo();
   //$('.nc-remove').toggle();
   var showBtn = null;
   if (showBtn == null) {
   $('.view-alternatives-btn img').attr("src","../images/wsj_hide_alternatives_btn.gif");
   $('#nc-alternate-wines').show();
   showBtn = 1;
   console.log(showBtn);
   }
   else if (showBtn == 1) {
   $('.view-alternatives-btn img').attr("src","../images/wsj_view_alternatives_btn.gif");
   $('#nc-alternate-wines').hide();
   console.log("this " + showBtn);
   }
   return false; 
  });
```

Comment: What if the button is clicked 3 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable will never exist when you click, because it is initialized inside the function, then lost when the function ends.

If you want to store it between clicks, create it outside the click handler.

```
  var showBtn = null;

  $('.view-alternatives-btn').live('click', function() {

     //$("#nc-alternate-wines").scrollTo();
     //$('.nc-remove').toggle();

   if (showBtn == null) {
       $('.view-alternatives-btn img').attr("src","../images/wsj_hide_alternatives_btn.gif");
       $('#nc-alternate-wines').show();
       showBtn = 1;
       console.log(showBtn);
   }
   else if (showBtn == 1) {
       $('.view-alternatives-btn img').attr("src","../images/wsj_view_alternatives_btn.gif");
       $('#nc-alternate-wines').hide();
       console.log("this " + showBtn);
   }
   return false; 
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're *always* setting it to `null` when the button is clicked, so you'll never reach the `else if`...

You might instead use a global variable, or [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

Answer (score 1):

`showBtn` is a local variable, so its value is not persisted across `click` events.

Move `var showBtn = null;` outside the `click` handler.

However, the best way to do this is to call jQuery's [`toggle` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle).  (Except that `toggle` cannot be used with `live`)

Answer (score 0):

you're declaring `showBtn` as a local variable, so it only exists until the end of your click handler. you need a global variable if you want set it to 1 the first click and be able to check for 1 on the second click.

Answer (score 0):

First issue is that the variable `showBtn` is `local` to the function, so it gets re-defined each time you execute the script..
Secondly you set its value right before checking it .. so it will always be set to `null`..

since you bind it with the `live` method which implies dynamic elements, i would use the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method.

```
$('.view-alternatives-btn').live('click', function() {

var showBtn = $(this).data('showBtn');
//$("#nc-alternate-wines").scrollTo();
   //$('.nc-remove').toggle();
   if ( showBtn ) {
   $('.view-alternatives-btn img').attr("src","../images/wsj_hide_alternatives_btn.gif");
   $('#nc-alternate-wines').show();
   $(this).data('showBtn',true);
   console.log(showBtn);
   }
   else{
   $('.view-alternatives-btn img').attr("src","../images/wsj_view_alternatives_btn.gif");
   $('#nc-alternate-wines').hide();
   console.log("this " + showBtn);
   }
   return false; 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Awesome, thanks for the help everyone!

I got it working!

```
  var showBtn = 1;

  $('.view-alternatives-btn').live('click', function() {

     //$("#nc-alternate-wines").scrollTo();
     //$('.nc-remove').toggle();

   if (showBtn == 1) {
       $('.view-alternatives-btn img').attr("src","../images/wsj_hide_alternatives_btn.gif");
       $('#nc-alternate-wines').show();
       showBtn = 0;
       console.log(showBtn);
   }
   else {
       $('.view-alternatives-btn img').attr("src","../images/wsj_view_alternatives_btn.gif");
       $('#nc-alternate-wines').hide();
       console.log("this " + showBtn);
       showBtn = 1;
   }
   return false; 
  });
```